# Cannot read a sorted array with Foreach statement

Tags: c#

I have been learning C# these last couple of weeks and slowly I am getting better but I have ran into a problem that I just can't get my head around.

Firstly I can read my array of files if I don't sort them by LastWriteTime.

```
      mDirectory = @"\\11.11.11.11\Excel"; 
      mFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(mDirectory, "*.xls");

     foreach (string file in mFiles)
      {
                 ................
       }
```

This works without a problem. But i need to sort the file list by date modified. So I used the following

```
                  if (Directory.Exists(mDirectory))
                     {
                      DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(mDirectory);
                      FileInfo[] logFiles = di.GetFiles("*.xls");


                      DateCompareFileInfo dateCompareFileInfo = new DateCompareFileInfo();

                      Array.Sort(logFiles, dateCompareFileInfo);

                      Array.Reverse(logFiles);
```

Which calls to this class -

```
   class DateCompareFileInfo : IComparer<FileInfo>
                        {
                            public int Compare(FileInfo fi1, FileInfo fi2)
                            {
                                int result;
                                if (fi1.LastWriteTime == fi2.LastWriteTime)
                                {
                                    result = 0;
                                }
                                else if (fi1.LastWriteTime < fi2.LastWriteTime)
                                {
                                    result = 1;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    result = -1;
                                }

                                return result;
                            }
                        }
```

I have debugged to check that the files are sorted the way I want them and its perfect.

So now I want to read the files like so  -

```
 foreach (string file in logFiles)
     {
      ...........
        }
```

When I run it I get the following error  **Error    2   Cannot convert type 'System.IO.FileInfo' to 'string'**

If anyone could shed some light on what I am doing wrong I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I dare claiming the `GetFiles()` method in your first code snippet returns `FileInfo` objects, not strings.

Comment: I find it quite interesting that the first version shall work. As Wormbo mentioned GetFiles() returns an array of FileInfos not string so that the FileInfo to string conversion works would be quite strange there. Are you absolutely SURE that it works?

Comment: @Thomas, `Directory.GetFiles` returns a `string[]` where as `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` returns a `FileInfo[]`.

Comment: Ah yepp. too unspecific google searches for the getFiles method was why I only saw the wrong (directoryinfo) method. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (string file in logFiles)
     {
      ...........
     }
```

in your code, logFiles is an array of FileInfo type and you are trying to iterate logFiles as a string. Also FileInfo is not inherited from string, thus it can't be converted to string. 
For that you need to use 'var' or exact type.

```
 foreach (var file in logFiles)
         {
          ...........
         }
```

or

```
 foreach (FileInfo file in logFiles)
         {
          ...........
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding 
"When I run it I get the following error Error 2 Cannot convert type 'System.IO.FileInfo' to 'string'"

```
foreach (var fileInfo in logFiles)
{
    var path = fileInfo.FullName;
    //do whatever you want
}
```

or

```
foreach (var filePath in logFiles.Select(fileInfos=>fileInfos.FullName))
{        
    //do whatever you want, filePath will be string which already contains FullName
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (FileInfo file in logFiles)
{
      var name = fileInfo.Name;
      ...........
}
```

I suggest you all the time you can use this syntax

```
foreach(var file in logFiles)
```

then put your mouse on var and wait it will show the type

Answer (score 1):

The mainproblem why the first variant works but the second not is that you are using 2 different methods that have completely different returntypes (As can be seen in my comment to the question I also stumbled upon that, so it can happen easily as the methods themselves have the same name).

One thing to always keep in mind with .NET is that you have methods with the same name coming from different namesspaces which do different things. But now to topic.

At first you used:

```
System.Io.Directory.GetFiles
```

This method returns an array of strings. That is why you can use foreach to store it in strings respectively.

Then in the second example you used GetFiles method from DirectoryInfo. This has the same basic functionality as the other method BUT returns an array of FileInfo objects instead of string objects.

That is why a foreach (string .......) over the results of the DirectoryInfo Getfiles fails as the foreach expects a string as element of the array and not a FileInfo object.

So what you can do is two different things

1. Use FileInfo instread of string in the foreach loop
2. Convert the returned array so that you get strings instead of FileInfos

   2. is only adviceable if you have linq which you mentioned in a comment that you don't have available. It is only adviceable with linq available because else you would have to iterate manually over the whole array and then create an array of string objects over which you can iterate.

Thus option 2 we can forget. So lets look at option 1. Here you can iterate over the returned array and just expect FileInfo objects. If you need the filename in "file" you can just get it inside the foreach loop. Thus putting it all together:

```
foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in mFiles)
{
    string file = fileInfo.FullName; 
    // that is if you want the FULL path included else only 
    // fileInfo.Name instead of fileInfo.FullName
}
```